# How to prove/disprove distribution of division over union

Tags: relational-algebra

How can I prove distribution of division over union in relational algebra, i.e. the following:

$$(R \cup S) / X \overset{?}{=} (R / X) \cup (S / X)$$

Comment: Maybe a proof my induction would do?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i figured it out. Let $L_1$, $L_2$ be relation sets where $L_2$ is a subset of $L_1$. We know $R$ and $S$ are subsets of $L_1$ and $X$ is a subset of $L_2$. Since we do not know whether $X$ is a subset of $R$ and $S$, we can give the following counter example:

Suppose 
$$\begin{align*}
  L_1 &=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), \\
  R &= (1,2,3,4), \\
  S &= (5,6,7)\; \text{and}\\ X &= (1,3).
\end{align*}$$
Then, $(R \cup S) / X = (2,4,5,6,7)$ whereas $R / X$ and $S / X$ are illegal.